# How to find key where value is array with certain key using php?

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

For simple arrays with key value pairs, we can easily locate the key based on the value using `array_search()`. But I have an array in which the values may be a string or an array, and need to find the key where the value is an array with specific keys.

```
$myArray = array(
  0 => string_value,
  1 => string_value2,
  3 => array(
         'config' => array(
           'option1' => value1,
           'option2' => value2,
         ),
       ),
  4 => string_value3,
);
```

I need to find the key for the element where the child array has a key `config` -- i.e. I should search for config and return `3`.

I'd prefer not to cycle through the array. Not a big deal if that's the only option. But I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to locate that key.

Comment: There's no other way except checking every item.

Comment: And you have tried WHAT?

Comment: If you already have a way of doing this (like iterating through all elements) and just wonder if there are a better way, I would recommend posting your working solution on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use array_filter to filter the array with config.

```
$o = array_filter($array, function($v){return !empty($v['config']) ? true : false;});
var_dump(array_keys($o));
```

Comment: This was definitely the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate items of array and check value of every item in loop. Check if `$item["config"]` setted in loop, return index of loop item.

```
$index;
foreach ($myArray as $key => $item){
    if (isset($item["config"]))
        $index = $key;
}
echo $index;
```

See result of code in [demo](https://3v4l.org/TLBTY)

Comment: And add a `break`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson If `$item['config']` allway is array, you can use `is_array()` but in question both of them work.

Comment: You are correct. I misread the question. He wants `$item` to be an array, not necessarily `$item['config']`.